# Gelfand triple for tensor product of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Is there any dense embeding $\to$ that makes
$H^1_0(D) \otimes L^2(\Gamma) \to L^2(D) \otimes L^2(\Gamma) \to (H^1_0(D) \otimes L^2(\Gamma))^{*}$
a Gelfand tripe?

In fact we may only answere to the question of existense of dense embedin
 $$H^1_0(D) \otimes L^2(\Gamma) \to L^2(D) \otimes L^2(\Gamma)$$
Noting that in this case we know that there exists dese embedings $H^1_0(D) \to L^2(D)$ and $L^2(\Gamma) \to L^2(\Gamma)$, now the question may change into answering the question "Do Tensor product keeps the existense of  dense embeding?"

Am I right?

One may help me in constructing such embeding (if exists).

Edited:

Using comments and answeres of dear friends specially dear @Paul Garret. Also the topic is improved.

Any guide is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your intention about tensor products? For $\Gamma$ a finite set, obviously this follows from the Gelfand-triple-ness of the sequence without the $L^2(\Gamma)$, but with infinite-dimensional $L^2(\Gamma)$, the sticking point may be exactly that no tensor product of infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces has the duality you want... is this what you are addressing, in fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's a typo (namely, that $(H^1_o(D)\otimes L^2(D))^*$ should replace the $L^2(D)$ by $L^2(\Gamma)$):

... then I still suspect that this question is not the question intended, because the answer for the question (with presumed typo corrected) is a sort of simple "yes": given any notion of tensor product (whether or not it has the properties categorically required of a tensor product...), if it's a Hilbert space, then the question can be abstracted to: for a Hilbert space $X$ with a continuous inclusion to a Hilbert space $Y$ so that $X$ has dense image, is $X\to Y \to X^*$ a Gelfand triple? Certainly, if all we need is a continuous map $Y\to X^*$, which can be obtained by composing the Hilbert-space adjoint of $X\to Y$ with the conjugation map making $Y^*\approx Y$.

But maybe this is not the real question, or more is required of "Gelfand triple" in some context?